# Will an unchecked exception thrown and caught inside a method annotated with spring's @Transactional still cause the transaction to rollback?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-transactions

I have method in my service class.

```
@Transactional
public void serviceMethod {
    dao.daoMethod();
}

public void daoMethod() {//dao.daoMethod
    //some code
    try {
        //some more code that throws an unchecked exception
    } catch(Exception exception) {
       //do something -- no exceptions generated/thrown from here
    }
    //some more code
 }
```

Will this result in the transaction rolling back?
If the Unchecked exception was thrown from within a method that was called from the try block would it be any different?

Answer (score 3):

No, the transaction will only be rolled back in case of an uncaught exception.

The transactional interceptors "wrap" around the calls of the annotated methods; they cannot see what happens *inside* them.

Comment: Hey Haroldo,
Thanks for the answer as well as the explanation behind it. I will dig into it.

Answer (score 1):

In your case it will silently ignore the exception. You didn't do anything inside the catch block. This is not advised at all.

Comment: Hey Yohannes. Thanks for your answer. For legal reasons, I cannot put the actually code here but in reality I will be logging the exception for audit and future action and expect no exceptions to arise from there.

Comment: the transaction rolls back only  if the exception thrown is unchecked exception. Moreover, inside your catch block please throw unchecked exception after your log message in order to  rollback when unchecked exception occurred. Look also into this https://www.catalysts.cc/en/wissenswertes/spring-transactional-rollback-on-checked-exceptions/.

Answer (score 1):

If you catch an Exception in the try-catch block and you did some actions to handle this Exception - a rollback will not happen. In the case with RuntimeException, by default - the rollback will occur.

You can specify, which exceptions should cause the rollback. **@Transactional(rollbackFor = MyCheckedException.class)**

https://resourcepool.io/2014/11/16/java-quickies-what-you-wish-you-knew-about-spring-transactional-annotation/

https://www.catalysts.cc/wissenswertes/spring-transactional-rollback-on-checked-exceptions/

Comment: Hey Merkurev,
Thanks for the links. Really appreciate the help.